# Why I can't retrieve old request values?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I am flashing request input like this:

```
Input::flash();
```

Then, in the next request, I try to get old values:

```
$subject_id= $request->old('subject_id');
```

but I get $subject_id as null
So, what could be the reason?

Comment: Did you try to use `$request->flash();`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I first tried before trying Input::flash();

Comment: I believe `old()` is available only when you do something like `redirect()->back()->withInput()`.

Comment: In my case, the user will post a request to another controller handler, and I try to get previous inputs from there, but it returns null..

Comment: Make sure the session is being used.

Comment: If you are not redirecting anything, it should be available just as `$request->subject_id`. Could you show us more code?

Comment: I will check when return home, thanks